# Demonstrate that (p → q) → ((q → r) → (p → r)) is a tautology.

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I'm struggling to demonstrate that

```
(p → q) → ((q → r) → (p → r))
```

is a tautology. I know that :

```
(p → q) → ((¬q ∨ r) → (¬p ∨ r))
        → (¬(¬q ∨ r) ∨ ¬(¬p ∨ r))
        → ((q ∧ ¬r) ∨ (p ∧ ¬r))     // De Morgan
        → ((q ∧ ¬r) ∨ (p ∧ ¬r))
```

I could also use distributivity to get to :

```
        → (¬r ∧ (p ∨ q))
```

Moving forward :

```
¬(p → q) ∨ (¬r ∧ (p ∨ q))
¬(¬p ∨ q) ∨ (¬r ∧ (p ∨ q))
(p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬r ∧ (p ∨ q))     // De Morgan
```

But I'm stuck there. Any help yould be appreciated !

Comment: Why not turn the final implication into an or?

Comment: ¬(p → q) ∨ (¬r ∧ (p ∨ q))

Comment: I don't quite see how that helps... But thanks.

Comment: @BobLeponge you have an extra negation on your second line down. There should not be a $\neg$ simple in front of $(\neg p \vee r)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't just apply Implication Equivalence to the last two implications, apply it to all four then apply DeMorgan's Laws and simplify.

$\begin{align}
(p \to q) \to ((q \to r) \to (p \to r)) && \text{Given}
\\
\neg (\neg p \lor q) \lor (\neg (\neg q \lor r) \lor (\neg p \lor r)) && \text{Implication Equivalence}
\\
(p \land \neg q) \lor (q\land \neg r)\lor (\neg p \lor r)&& \text{DeMorgan's}
\\
\neg p \lor (p \land \neg q) \lor r \lor (q\land \neg r)&& \text{Commuate and Associate}
\\
\ddots & & \vdots
\end{align}$

Comment: Thank you very much. I managed to complete it from your line 4. Much appreciated !